# Group product Options

Tags: magento2.3, custom-options, grouped-products

If products in a group need an additional option, how would I create that option?

> For example; if they're ordering ceiling lights, the grouped products
>   are the different sizes, but afterwards they need to select either a
>   handheld remote or a wall switch.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Set Group Product Options By Using Follwing Steps

1. Catalog ->Product->
   Select Group Product From Add Product Dropdown
2. And Finally you can add multiple products to group using Group Products Section

And If you want to create size related option than it is better to use configurable products,
you can select custom options tab in add product form with configurable product 
and set your options as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks.. but I don't think you read my question. I have the items in the group already, what I need is additional options on top of that. The different sizes are all already in the group. After they select one, I want them to also choose either a hand or wall remote. I don't want to add the remotes to the group, because then it makes the remote by itself the "starting at" price which is misleading. the site is for industrial project installs so we need the quantity that is on the grouped products. Currently, I am just using the cross-sell for the remotes but i'm hoping there's a better method.